# Scipy and Numpy upgrade generates "TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64')"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I'm converting a code from Python 2.7 to Python 3.8.

In its Python 2.7 version, I had to use downgraded versions of scipy and numpy in order to avoid a TypeError (see below). With Python 3.8, these downgraded versions of scipy and numpy are not available anymore and I get this error, which I'm unable to fix.

**1. Setup**

Previous : MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, Python 2.7.16, numpy 1.9.0, scipy 1.0.1

New : MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, Python 3.8.6, numpy 1.20.3, scipy 1.4.0

**2. Code**

It happens when calling `scipy.integrate.odeint` :

```
y_trajectory = scipy.integrate.odeint(growth_a_derivs, y_start, t_array, atol=eps, args=myargs)
```

With `growth_a_derivs` a function, `y_start, t_array` numpy arrays with dtype `float64`, `eps` a float and `myargs` a tuple of length 1 containing a dictionary.

**3. Error**

The following traceback pops :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
  <long blah blah blah>

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyxcosmo/icosmo_cosmo.py", line 149, in growth_a
    result=growth_a_ode(cosmo, a, unnorm=unnorm)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyxcosmo/icosmo_cosmo.py", line 671, in growth_a_ode
    y_trajectory = scipy.integrate.odeint(growth_a_derivs, y_start, t_array, atol=eps, args=myargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py", line 242, in odeint
    output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

So the last line is in scipy's integrate pckg, the full call to odeint is :

```
    output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
                         full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
                         ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords,
                         int(bool(tfirst)))
```

Inside this, the error is in a compiled scipy `.so` file, thus I can't analyze this error further. I just know that the call to growth_a_derivs isn't problematic (its print() calls all work). But I don't know whether its a numpy or scipy problem, and how to overcome it.

***4. Resolution !***

I was able to understand the problem thanks to @RFoxtea answer below.
I believe this issue was caused by the change in numpy version.
The output of `growth_a_derivs` is :

```
np.array([f1,f2])
```

with :

```
type(f1) = numpy.float64
type(f2) = numpy.ndarray
f2.shape = (1,)
```

With numpy 1.9, this gives :

```
np.array([f1,f2]) = [1.234, np.array([1.234])]
np.array([f1,f2]).dtype = numpy.float64
```

With numpy 1.20, this gives :

```
np.array([f1,f2]) = [1.234, np.array([1.234])]
np.array([f1,f2]).dtype = numpy.object
```

And that is not accepted by `scipy.integrate.odeint`.
However, notice that `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` is ok with that.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point in running `scipy.integrate.odeint`, Numpy is told to convert an array of Python objects into an array of floats, and it's answering you that it can't do that. Your description suggests the problem has to be with `y_start`, `t_start` or (maybe, I'm not sure) the return value of `growth_a_derivs`. Please make sure that these all have an appropriate `dtype` that can be converted into a float. Could be very easy to fix.

Comment: Ok, so I updated the question to add that `y_start` and `t_start`with good dtype. But the output of growth_a_derivs wasn't. This is finally because of the change in numpy version. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RFoxtea who provided the right solution.

However there is an interesting alternative. You can use [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) instead of `scipy.integrate.odeint`.

Solve_ivp can handle an output of `fun`that is with dtype `object`.